# How i Solve my wordpress php header update file problem

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello every one i want to add some the below coding in wordpress php header but it showing this message 
Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.
i need to add the below coding but when i click update file then not updated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
      marquee{
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 800;
      color: #8ebf42;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <marquee>A scrolling text created with HTML Marquee element.</marquee>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to put in header ? Style you have added between head tags ? If there is only problem in connecting to back-end of site check your internet connection.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with the FTP connection to your server or with the related UI of your webhost ("click "update file" sounds like that), not a php or wordpress problem (it definitely has nothing to do with the code you posted). You should contact the support of your webhost.